# How to have exim4 listen to port instead of exim

Tags: networking, server, ssh, email, exim

So I was adding ports for exim4 to listen to through the following command /usr/sbin/exim -bd -oX  and accidentally made it so that exim would listen to ports 465, 587, 2525. I tried running /usr/sbin/exim4 -bd -oX  but after checking with netstat -plan |grep exim it still shows exim as what's listening to those ports. How can I fix this? How can I delete exim from listening to said ports?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: 20.04LTS (need to add more characters)